# Flutter Hot Reload Not Working on Android Device

Tags: android, flutter, hot-reload

I am unable to enjoy hot reload when running my flutter app on android device (I ma trying on v2013 => vivo 51ys), I keep making changes and pressing r in console does nothing at all look at imege1

**Hot reload is working great when I use linux as target platform for same flutter app (same code)** look at imege2

If hot reload is working for same code on linux, it must be working on android, but still let me present my code of main file, I need to change text `Hot reload not works` and see the change after pressing `r`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main() => runApp(const MyApp());
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home: Scaffold(appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Hot reload not works!!'))));
  }
}
```

Also hot **reload works quite fine when I am using same devices (PC and smart phone) while developing app with react-native** when I press r in

Hot reload does not work for same code when run on android device (I ma trying on v2013 => vivo 51ys), I keep making changes and pressing r in console does nothing at all look at imege2

flutter doctor says everything is fine. Am using latest stable flutter 3.13.4. look at imege3.

MY PC OS is ubunutu 22 (image4). I am using not network proxy. **What else could be the problem? How I can be able to use hot reload of flutter?**

Note:
I think there is **nothing to do with VSCODE or android studio** as by simply editing/saving dart file and press r in console must reload without even having editor.

**Images**

image1

[image: image1]

image2

[image: image2]

image3

[image: image3]

image4

[image: image4]